# Script to move files from sub directories to root folder

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following directory and sub directories structure:

```
eva tree
.
├── 1061
│   └── 2022
│       └── 09
│           └── 21
│               └── a0e51f58-5057-4002-b4c4-d3fb870e9b3a.json
├── 1769
│   └── 2022
│       └── 08
│           └── 30
│               └── e36d8e21-5184-489f-89b5-eb1fd5eba5f6.json
├── 1991
│   └── 2022
│       └── 09
│           └── 16
│               └── 1d0a4162-7e66-44c8-8b61-f3bc5dbdb107.json
```

I need to move all .json files to root folder `eva`.

Expected output:

```
.
│a0e51f58-5057-4002-b4c4-d3fb870e9b3a.json
│e36d8e21-5184-489f-89b5-eb1fd5eba5f6.json
│1d0a4162-7e66-44c8-8b61-f3bc5dbdb107.json
```

How can I do it using bash?

Comment: If the structure is this uniform, simply `mv */*/*/*/* .`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec mv {} . \;`

- `find .` searches across the current directory;
- `-type f` all objects of type `f` (aka file);
- `-name '*.json'` file names that ends with the `.json`;
- `-exec [COMMAND]\;` for each file found, run `[COMMAND]`;
- `mv {} .`, the curly brackets `{}` represent the found file, the command `mv`es it to the current directory (`.`)

Comment: A more secure and efficient version would be `find . -type f -name "*.json" -exec mv -t . '{}' +` which will build a command line from the files in each directory invoking `mv` on a group of files instead of once per-file. (if there is only one .json file per-dir, that's not an improvement)